# How do I choose or reserve a user and it appears to me in message notifications and returns to me with a message in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Well, I have a project for electronic contracts for lawyers, and I have that the user (the citizen) makes a reservation for the lawyer, and it appears to him in the notifications, and the lawyer sends him a copy of the contract as a file, what do I do? I am distracted

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What do you have done? What do you have that's not working (show the code)?

Comment: I'm new to Laravel. I want to send messages, reservations, or requests between users